# WebRTC video conference between Android and Desktop users

Tags: javascript, android, webrtc

I'm building a simple video conferencing system.
I'm using the following code as my base -> https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/video-conferencing/

It works perfectly on Windows and OSX, they can connect and chat with each other, but I cannot connect or see the video from an Android device.

I'm wondering what the best way of getting this working on Android so that an Android client and a Desktop client can chat together.

The android client seems to connect, but it just doesn't show the video to the PC user and vice versa.

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: When trying to establish an Android <-> desktop connection, what browser are you using on desktop? If it's Safari 11 on macOS, the connection may not work due to a video codec discrepancy. The case is the same as with iOS Safari: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210969/1712145

Comment: I'm using Chrome to create the "channel" on Windows 10 Desktop. Are there maybe possible modifications needed to get the code working correctly on an Android browser ? Such as a small compatibility fix such as an" autoplay" feature, for example?